# Accumulation layer cause by threshold voltage

Tags: mosfet

Is \$V_T\$ , the voltage that just causes an accumulation layer to form in the conducting channel is larger the closer you are to the source contact in MOSFET?

Comment: Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_voltage and learn on what parameters Vt depends upon. Now explain how the source contact could physically influence (or not) Vt. Now think about the drain contact, is that physically any different from the source contact? Does it influence Vt? -1 for silly yes/no question without doing much research.

Comment: The voltage on Drain can be dozens if not hundreds of volts different from the Source voltage.

Answer (score 0):

\$V_t \$ is the threshold voltage, which is the voltage when the device is considered to be 'on' and conducting. This happens when \$V_t > V_{gs} \$.

Below is a animation of the electron density in a simulated mosfet, when Vg(s) is greater than roughly 0.5V the device starts to conduct, although conduction is a relative term.

[image]